# Access Java variable by its name as a String

Tags: java

I have declared 10 `ArrayList`s with names `arraylist1`, `arraylist2` and so on.

I want to dynamically change variable name in a for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
   arraylist + (i).clear();
   //arraylist1.clear();
   //arraylist2.clear();
   //arraylist3.clear();
   //arraylist4.clear();
   //arraylist5.clear();

}
```

Is it possible? If so what is format to do so?

Comment: No, you are not able to change variable name in java (at least not in conventional way). Is it any reason why you want to do this?

Comment: @user902383: I have created new arraylist's and method and I want to call only the method once in a loop and clear arraylist then add values for that arraylist.

Comment: If you have several lists, and you want to clean then in list, why not put them into list, or other collection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not address a variable with its name as string (except with reflection, but that's an overkill for this task).

You can add all these ArrayList's to another List. This is more flexible and, thus, a better option.

```
List<List<ContactDetails>> lists2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    lists2.add(new ArrayList<ContactDetails>());
}
```

Or add them to an array and access them by array indexes:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<ContactDetails>[] lists = new List[10];
for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i ++) {
    lists[i] = new ArrayList<ContactDetails>();
}
```

Now:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
   lists[i].clear();
   lists2.get(i).clear();
}
```

As both List and array are [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), you can use the [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) syntax:

```
for (List list : lists)
{
   list.clear();
}

for (List list : lists2) {
    list.clear();
}
```

#### If you know how to achieve the same with Lambdas / Stream API, please add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply..What if I have arraylist of something like this: ArrayList<ContactDetails> arraylist1;

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix. I am getting warning "Type safety: The expression of type List[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<ContactDetails>[]" - Do I need to worry about it?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: I'm sorry, I was typing too fast without having made a test. I think the best way (without any warning nedded to be supressed) is the variant with the list of lists (lists2)

Comment: @xmoex I agree about a list of lists, it's the most flexible option. The `new List<ContactDetails>[10]` was in my first version, so I made the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If the `ArrayList`s are class properties, you can achieve this with [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html):

```
((ArrayList) getClass().getField("arraylist" + i).get(this)).clear();
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @Stewart why would you think it was?

Comment: @Armand sorry, I misread your comment =) Thought it was OP asking about the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with reflection. But I do not recommend it.

```
public class SoTest {

    @Test
    public void testWithReflection() throws Exception {
        final MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final Field field = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("list" + i);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            final List<String> value = (List<String>) field.get(myClass);
            value.clear();
        }
    }

    class MyClass {
        private List<String> list0 = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> list4 = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> list5 = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> list6 = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> list7 = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> list8 = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> list9 = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```